# Abrir e ler uma planilha Excel pelo Lazarus Usando OLE

Tags: microsoft-excel, lazarus

O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente em Delphi, porém quando portei para o Lazarus, o código compila sem problemas, porém na hora da execução ocorre uma exceção e o programa é fechado.

```
function TFMain.AbrePlanilha(NomePlan: String): Boolean;
begin
 Try
    Result := False;
    if not FileExists(NomePlan) Then
       exit;
    Mensagem('Abrindo excel, aguarde...');
    ExcelApp := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application'); // <- até aqui OK

    // O erro ocorre aqui abaixo.
    // ==============================================
       ExcelPlan := ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open(NomePlan);
    // ==============================================

    Mensagem('Planilha Excel ' + NomePlan + ' aberta OK!');
    Result := True;
    Update;
 Finally
 End;

end;
```

O curioso é que o código é o mesmo para o Delphi e para o Lazarus, inclusive está incluido em uma lib de uso comum para ambos, e no Lazarus ocorre isso.

O que estou deixando passar?

Comment: Qual é a excepção?

Comment: Projeto Almox_importaItens elevou classe exceção 'External: ?'.

 No endereço 7FFEE8180F20
 
Na janela assembler do depurador:

 00007FFEE8180EE0 eb0c                     jmp    0x7ffee8180eee <ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+398>

Verifiquei se estou declarando a units Comobj,  e está OK.